# How do you create a scrollbar that recognizes scrolling only for the current topmost container using css?

Tags: html, css

I have two containers.  The bottommost one creates a scrollbar because it has a height that is large enough to need that.  When the topmost container is visible above the bottommost container id like the scrollbar to work for **ONLY** that container.  Right now scrolling affects the bottom and top containers. How do you go about doing this?  Thank you!

Here is the code for what is happening:
http://jsfiddle.net/5wNDX/68/

CSS:

```
#outer {
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
bottom: 0px;
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
display: block;
font-size: 14px;
height: 563px;
left: 0px;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: scroll;
position: fixed;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 1479px;
z-index: 9999;
}

#inner {
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border:4px solid #000;
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
display: block;
font-size: 14px;
height: 900px;
margin:0 auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
position: static;
width: 750px;
z-index: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body> 
    <div>Large block of text</div>
    <div id='outer'>   
      <div id='inner'>
        test
      </div>   
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: if you want your `#inner` element doesn't move when you scroll, you have to set it to `position:fixed` and position it with `left/right` and/or `top/bottom`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to give `position: absolute` to your `#inner` div to accomplish this.